# How do I run a Perl script from within a Perl script?

Tags: perl, ipc

I've got a Perl script that needs to execute another Perl script. This second script can be executed directly on the command line, but I need to execute it from within my first program. I'll need to pass it a few parameters that would normally be passed in when it's run standalone (the first script runs periodically, and executes the second script under a certain set of system conditions).

Preliminary Google searches suggest using backticks or a system() call. Are there any other ways to run it? (I'm guessing yes, since it's Perl we're talking about :P ) Which method is preferred if I need to capture output from the invoked program (and, if possible, pipe that output as it executes to stdout as though the second program were invoked directly)?

(Edit: oh, **now** SO suggests some related questions. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109124/run-external-process-from-perl-capture-stderr-stdout-and-the-process-exit-code) is close, but not exactly the same as what I'm asking. The second program will likely take an hour or more to run (lots of I/O), so I'm not sure a one-off invocation is the right fit for this.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The location of your current perl interpreter can be found in the special variable `$^X`.  This is important if perl is not in your path, or if you have multiple perl versions available but which to make sure you're using the same one across the board.

When executing external commands, including other Perl programs, determining if they actually ran can be quite difficult.  Inspecting `$?` can leave lasting mental scars, so I prefer to use [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::System::Simple) (available from the CPAN):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system capture);

# Run a command, wait until it finishes, and make sure it works.
# Output from this program goes directly to STDOUT, and it can take input
# from your STDIN if required.
system($^X, "yourscript.pl", @ARGS);

# Run a command, wait until it finishes, and make sure it works.
# The output of this command is captured into $results.
my $results = capture($^X, "yourscript.pl", @ARGS);
```

In both of the above examples any arguments you wish to pass to your external program go into `@ARGS`.  The shell is also avoided in both of the above examples, which gives you a small speed advantage, and avoids any unwanted interactions involving shell meta-characters.  The above code also expects your second program to return a zero exit value to indicate success; if that's not the case, you can specify an additional first argument of allowable exit values:

```
 # Both of these commands allow an exit value of 0, 1 or 2 to be considered
 # a successful execution of the command.

 system( [0,1,2], $^X, "yourscript.pl", @ARGS );
 # OR
 capture( [0,1,2, $^X, "yourscript.pl", @ARGS );
```

If you have a long-running process and you want to process its data *while* it's being generated, then you're probably going to need a piped open, or one of the more heavyweight IPC modules from the CPAN.

Having said all that, any time you need to be calling another Perl program from Perl, you may wish to consider if using a module would be a better choice.  Starting another program carries quite a few overheads, both in terms of start-up costs, and I/O costs for moving data between processes.  It also significantly increases the difficulty of error handling.  If you can turn your external program into a module, you may find it simplifies your overall design.

All the best,

*Paul*

Answer (score 38):

You can just *do* it.

```
{
    local @ARGV = qw<param1 param2 param3>;
    do '/home/buddy/myscript.pl';
}
```

Prevents the overhead of loading in another copy of perl.

Answer (score 13):

I can think of a few ways to do this. You already mentioned the first two, so I won't go into detail on them.

1. backticks:   `` $retVal = `perl somePerlScript.pl`; ``
2. `system()` call
3. `eval`

The `eval` can be accomplished by slurping the other file into a string (or a list of strings), then 'eval'ing the strings. Heres a sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open PERLFILE, "<somePerlScript.pl";
undef $/;   # this allows me to slurp the file, ignoring newlines
my $program = <PERLFILE>;
eval $program;
```

4 . do:

```
do 'somePerlScript.pl'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier and more concise to simply use 'do'?

Comment: Good list. Could you elaborate on the differences? For example, the code evaluated with `do FILE` cannot see lexicals in the enclosing scope; `eval STRING` does. Etc.

Answer (score 12):

You already got good answers to your question, but there's always the posibility to take a different point of view: maybe you should consider refactoring the script that you want to run from the first script. Turn the functionality into a module. Use the module from the first and from the second script.

Comment: I considered that a while ago, but wrote it off for two reasons. First, another developer is working on the second program, and second, the second one was finished months ago, and this first script to automate it was just thought of. If I did this over again, I'd probably do modules instead.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to asynchronously call your external script -you just want to launch it and not wait for it to finish-, then :

```
# On Unix systems, either of these will execute and just carry-on
# You can't collect output that way
`myscript.pl &`;
system ('myscript.pl &');    

# On Windows systems the equivalent would be
`start myscript.pl`;
system ('start myscript.pl');

# If you just want to execute another script and terminate the current one
exec ('myscript.pl');
```

Answer (score 6):

Use backticks if you need to capture the output of the command.

Use `system` if you do not need to capture the output of the command.

TMTOWTDI: so there are other ways too, but those are the two easiest and most likely.

Answer (score 5):

See the [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) documentation for several options for interprocess communication.

If your first script merely sets up the environment for the second script, you may be looking for `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

open(OUTPUT, "date|") or die "Failed to create process: $!\n";

while (<OUTPUT>)
{
  print;
}

close(OUTPUT);

print "Process exited with value " . ($? >> 8) . "\n";
```

This will start the process `date` and pipe the output of the command to the OUTPUT filehandle which you can process a line at a time.  When the command is finished you can close the output filehandle and retrieve the return value of the process.  Replace `date` with whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something like this to offload non-subroutines into an external file to make editing easier.  I actually made this into a subroutine.  The advantage of this way is that those "my" variables in the external file get declared in the main namespace.  If you use 'do' they apparently don't migrate to the main namespace.  Note the presentation below doesn't include error handling

```
sub getcode($) {
  my @list;
  my $filename = shift;
  open (INFILE, "< $filename");
  @list = <INFILE>;
  close (INFILE);
  return \@list;
}

# and to use it:

my $codelist = [];
$codelist = getcode('sourcefile.pl');
eval join ("", @$codelist);
```