# How to run a perl script N number of times WITHIN a perl script

Tags: perl

here is the skeleton script that i am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

=head1 NAME

webapp-1 harness - webapp-1 test

=head1 SYNOPSIS

    webapp-1 [OPTION]

    -v, --verbose  use verbose mode
    --help         print this help message

Where OPTION is an integer governing the number of times the script should be run

Examples:

    webapp-1 10 

=head1 DESCRIPTION

This is test harness to verify jira issue WEBAPP-1

=head1 AUTHOR

skahmed@mmm.com

=cut

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long qw(:config auto_help);
use Pod::Usage;

my $count = $ARGV;

main();

sub main {

    # Argument parsing
    my $verbose;
    GetOptions(
        'verbose'  => \$verbose,
    ) or pod2usage(1);
    pod2usage(1)unless @ARGV;

    while ($count) {
    printf "$count \n";
    # Here i want to run a perl script N number of times, with N being the ARGV to this command
    # capture( [0,1,2, $^X, "yourscript.pl", @ARGS );
    $count++;
    }
}
```

I also cannot use IPC::System since i cannot install it on the host (ubuntu 12.04) i am running it on.
What i am trying to do is to develop a perl test harness, which will run perl scripts to run processes, monitor database tables, etc and i can also control the timing of these scripts, based on the results i get from their execution.

one possible solution: for running a script N number of times based on @ARGV

```
foreach (1..$ARGV[0])
    {
      print "hello \n";
    }
```

Comment: take a look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364842/how-do-i-run-a-perl-script-from-within-a-perl-script?rq=1

Comment: Please can you clarify what the difficulty is in installing the module? Maybe we can overcome that. Also is `IPC::System` its exact name? No module of that name comes up when [searching MetaCPAN for it](https://metacpan.org/search?q=IPC%3A%3ASystem).

Comment: @Smylers its IPC::System::Simple
if i use cpanminus, i would have to be root, or have root permissions, to install the module, which i cannot get from sysOPS

Comment: i think i resolved this by using     system($^X, "hello.pl", @ARGV); , since the argument of the PARENT script is being used for the CHILD script. Now just have to figure out how to run it @ARGV number of times

Comment: Have you tied a [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)?

Comment: @user1883592 Thanks for introducing me to GNU Parallel, i will definitely try it out, this seems an easier and fast to implement option than trying to use https://github.com/autotest/autotest/wiki/ClientQuickStart , or https://github.com/amd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need root privs to install Cpan modules.

`cpanm` takes a `-l` option for installing into a specified directory, such as under `~/perl5/`.

Then in your program use the `local::lib` module to direct `perl` to where you installed modules. This is as simple as:

```
use local::lib '~/project/lib';
```

or, if you pick `~/perl5/` for installing to, simply:

```
use local::lib;
```

Both CpanMinus and `local::lib` can be bootstrap-installed as non-root:

- CpanMinus http://cpanmin.us
- `local::lib`: [https://metacpan.org/module/local::lib](https://metacpan.org/module/local%3a%3alib#The-bootstrapping-technique)

Together these give you the power of Cpan without requiring assistance from the server's sys-admin.

Comment: i have no access to cpanm ( just learned ) and when i try to install locally, i get lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/Config.pm is not writable, error

Comment: @kamal You can install `cpanm` locally with `wget -O - http://cpanmin.us | perl - --self-upgrade -l`