# get output value from one perl to another

Tags: perl, output

I have a perl file which in turn calls another perl file. I am expecting output from second perl file. How would I get the output ? Here is what my sample code looks like.

datetimetest.pl

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use DateTime;
print DateTime->now()->strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z");
print "\n";

my @perloutput = `/usr/bin/perl knowusername.pl`;
print "output:$perloutput[0]\n";
print "output 2: $perloutput[1]\n";

print "output 3: $perloutput[2]\n";
```

knowusername.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print $ENV{"LOGNAME"}."\n";

print "secondoutput\n";

print "thirdoutput\n";
```

I have edited answer above.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364842/how-do-i-run-a-perl-script-from-within-a-perl-script

Comment: @arkascha , how does that link help in my question ? I want to have output from one file to another file.

Comment: Sorry, did you even bother to _read_ the first answer in that question? It is about script output to stdout and how to capture it.

Comment: You're missing the `#` in your shebang line. Most likely a copy-paste error. Otherwise, this works for me.

Comment: @arkascha, I did look at the first answer, but my question is how do I pass output ? The answer shows how to capture them, not to pass them.

Comment: Ok guys, I resolved my problem. The only thing which I needed to add was "\n" at all print functions in knowusername.pl. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, always use `use warnings; use strict;`

Which would have caught your main issue here.

`$output` should be `$perloutput`

```
print "output:$perloutput[0]\n";
print "output 2: $output[1]\n";

print "output 3: $output[2]\n";
```