# Run perl script within perl script using named arguments

Tags: perl, ipc

I'm writing a Perl program that must run a few Perl scripts multiple times on different inputs.

The scripts I'm trying to use are `count.pl` and `statistic.pl` from
[`Text::NSP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::NSP).
I didn't write those myself so I don't want to try and refactor them into a module.

I looked at
[a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364842/how-do-i-run-a-perl-script-from-within-a-perl-script)
and figured out how to use the `system` method from
[`IPC::System::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple).

However, I want to make use of the named arguments in `count.pl` and `statistic.pl`. I haven't yet figured out how to do this. This is my current code:

```
system($^X, token="valid_tokens.txt", "/Users/cat/perl5/bin/statistic.pl", "ll.pm", "lab01_jav_bigrams.ll",
"/Users/cat/Perl_scripts/214_Final_project/lab01_java_bigrams.cnt");
```

And this is the error I get:

> Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at ngram_calcs.PL line 22, near ""valid_tokens.txt"," Bareword "token" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ngram_calcs.PL line 22.

It's worth noting that the code worked fine until I added the named argument. How do I supply a named argument to `IPC::System::Simple`? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Edit: Thanks, Haukex, I did have the wrong parameters, and using "--token=valid_tokens.txt" worked.

Even though the problem is solved, I'll share more context so that other people who see can benefit. On the commmand line I would type this:

```
count.pl -token validtokens.txt lab01_java_bigrams.cnt Users/cat/CS214/lab01_java.txt
statistic.pl -score 6.63 ll.pm lab01_java.ll lab01_java_bigrams.cnt
```

This is the correct perl code:

```
system($^X, "/Users/cat/perl5/bin/count.pl", "--token=valid_tokens.txt", "lab01_java_bigrams.cnt", $filename);
system($^X, "/Users/cat/perl5/bin/statistic.pl", "--score=6.63", "ll.pm", "lab01_java_bigrams.ll", "/Users/cat/Perl_scripts/214_Final_project/lab01_java_bigrams.cnt");
```

Comment: What is `token="valid_tokens.txt"`? I wouldn't expect that to be a valid use of "named arguments."  How do you invoke that program from the command line? You can pass arguments to a program only in a way it's written to take them. As for the error you show, what is the relevant code in "_ngram_calcs.PL_" (simplified if need be)?

Comment: You are not "_supplying a named argument to IPC::System::Simple_".  The module provides commands that replace the `system` builtin and which supply  to that program what is given to them.

Comment: I suggest that you edit the question and show how those programs are invoked on their own, from the command line, without the script you are writing. You'd also want to show the code of the script you are writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am confused about your `system` invocation. Looking at the sources of [`statistic.pl`](https://metacpan.org/source/TPEDERSE/Text-NSP-1.31/bin/statistic.pl) and [`count.pl`](https://metacpan.org/source/TPEDERSE/Text-NSP-1.31/bin/count.pl), it seems that only the latter takes a `token` argument, but you don't seem to be running `count.pl`. [`$^X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$%5EX) is the currently running Perl interpreter, which would normally be followed by any arguments to the *interpreter*, then the name of the script, then any arguments *to the script*, so placing the `token` argument before the script doesn't make sense to me.

If you are for example trying to pipe the output of `count.pl` into `statistic.pl`, you'll have to explain further, because that is something that [`IPC::System::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple) can't handle (at least not without invoking the shell, which I would recommend against), and you'd need a more advanced module like [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run). For now, I will assume you want to pass the `token` parameter to a script that supports it.

Command line arguments are just strings. If from a *NIX shell you were to write something like `./script.pl token="test file" foo bar`, then *the shell* would take over the interpretation of white space and quoting. `script.pl` will get a list of strings like `("token=test file", "foo", "bar")` (note how the shell took care of the quotes there).

This list of strings is what you need to pass to `system`, which is *not* necessarily the same as what you would type on the command line. It is up to the called program to interpret those arguments. The two scripts you are running use [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html), and the named arguments need to be prefixed by two dashes. So something like this should work:

```
system($^X, "/Users/cat/perl5/bin/count.pl", "--token=valid_tokens.txt", ...);
```

As for how to pass arguments that include special characters like quotes (which does not apply in this case), there are various syntaxes in Perl: `"--foo=\"bar\""`, `'--foo="bar"'`, or `q{--foo="bar"}` (see [Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your call to `statistic.pl` is broadly correct, the parameters to `system` need to look like this

```
system($^X,
    "/Users/cat/perl5/bin/statistic.pl",
    qq/token="valid_tokens.txt"/,
    "ll.pm",
    "lab01_jav_bigrams.ll",
    "/Users/cat/Perl_scripts/214_Final_project/lab01_java_bigrams.cnt"
);
```

i.e. all parameters belong *after* the program file, and the whole of the named parameter string must be enclosed in quotes

Please read the comment from **haukex** below for another potential error

Comment: The arguments to the script need to come after the script, not after `perl`. Also, [as far as I can tell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49728446/9300627), `token` needs two dashes and including the quotes in the argument would cause the target script to try and open a filename *including* those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this format?

```
system('/Users/cat/perl5/bin/statistic.pl  --token valid_tokens.txt  ll.pm  lab01_jav_bigrams.ll  /Users/cat/Perl_scripts/214_Final_project/lab01_java_bigrams.cnt');
```

But I check the source of the CPAN module, seems `token` is an option for `count.pl`, but not `statistic.pl`.

Anyway, any options can be specified similar to `--token valid_tokens.txt`.

Hope this help!

Comment: `system` with a single string argument has the disadvantage that it may cause the command to be passed through the default shell, causing shell metacharacters to make a difference. Unless those interpolations are specifically desired, the multi-argument form of `system` is safer.