# Can I run a Perl script from within another that is totally independent?

Tags: linux, perl

Within Linux I would like Perl script A to launch Perl script B.  However, I want script A to continue running without waiting for script B to return.  And I would like B to be totally independent so that when script A ends, script B is still running.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/364884/5267751

Comment: Yes, launch B followed by `&` to background the process without waiting for a return.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [fork() & friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)). For Perl implementation I would consult `man perlipc` or `man perlfork`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin However, I would like to ignore the return from system as I am running the script from a browser.

Comment: Yes, yes, exactly. No requirement you wait for anything. It's a fire-and-forget proposition -- just like any good missile brought to you by the same people that first gave us a $200 hammer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append an **`&`** sign at the end of your second script launch like this:

```
system("/script/myscript.sh $params &");
```

or

If your running one of this distros that won't let that work you'll have to use fork

or

```
Proc::Background
```

Comment: That's an oddly named Perl script, sir!

Comment: I went with you first choice.  But I added `> /dev/null &` to the end of the system call.  This made sure that I didn't get any unwanted output from the second script to interfere with my first.   Thanks