# How can I suppress system output when using nohup from Perl?

Tags: perl

In Perl I am starting a process using the nohup command. The command is below:

```
system("nohup myproc pe88 &");
```

This works fine and the process starts as expected. However I would like to suppress the following output of this command - which is:

```
Sending output to nohup.out
```

I must have this process redirecting all of it's output to nohup.out but I just don't want it displayed when I run my Perl program. I want to instead, print my own user friendly message. I've tried a few variants but nothing has worked for me yet.

Answer (score 5):

`"Sending output to nohup.out"` message [is sent to STDERR](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-56/nohup/nohup.c), so you can catch the STDERR via the usual methods

- either via shell: `system("nohup myproc pe88 2> /tmp/error_log.txt &");`

  Use `/dev/null` instead of `/tmp/error_log.txt` if you don't need stderr at all; and add "`> /tmp/myout.txt`" to redirect stdout.
- Or by capturing via Perl (don't use `system()` call, instead use `IPC::Open3` or [`capture` command from IPC::System::Simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109124/how-do-you-capture-stderr-stdout-and-the-exit-code-all-at-once-in-perl/109902#109902))

Comment: Note that by merely catching the STDERR, nohup doesn't even print the "sending output to nohup.out" message.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
system("nohup myproc pe88 >nohup.out 2>&1 &");
```

The man page for nohup says:

> If standard output is a terminal,
>   append output to 'nohup.out' if
>   possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise.
>   If standard error is a terminal,
>   redirect it to standard output.  To
>   save output to FILE, use `nohup
>   COMMAND > FILE'.

So if you explicitly redirect STDOUT and STDERR to nohup.out, then nohup doesn't print that message.  Granted, you don't get the automatic fallback to $HOME/nohup.out if nohup.out is unwritable, but you can check for that first if that's an issue.

Note that if you redirect just STDOUT, nohup prints a "redirecting stderr to stdout" message.