# Can IPC::System::Simple capture STDERR?

Tags: perl, redirect, stdout, stderr

I would like to invoke a script from my Perl code and capture its STDERR and STDOUT combined together.

I usually use `capture` from `IPC::System::Simple` but ti doesn't seem to allow capturing of STDERR.

Comment: That module sure seems like a lot of bother compared with just using Perl’s innate facilities.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you capture stderr, stdout, and the exit code all at once, in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109124/how-do-you-capture-stderr-stdout-and-the-exit-code-all-at-once-in-perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a POSIX system, you can do the following.  On Windows, this would work in [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

```
my @lines = capture("some command 2>&1");
```

However, if you want to distinguish STDERR lines from STDOUT lines, maybe you need to use [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.10.1/lib/IPC/Open3.pm) or the mis-named [IPC::Open3::Util](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/IPC-Open3-Utils/).

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect STDERR (file descriptor 2) to STDOUT (file descriptor 1) with `2>&1`.

From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) on the `qx//` operator:

> Because backticks do not affect
>   standard error, use shell file
>   descriptor syntax (assuming the shell
>   supports this) if you care to address
>   this. To capture a command's STDERR
>   and STDOUT together:
>
> $output = `cmd 2>&1`;

Comment: Just to clarify, this tells the shell to redirect filehandle 2 to filehandle 1.  Since filehandle 2 is STDERR and filehandle 1 is STDOUT, it does what you want.