# Logging from output in Perl

Tags: perl, logging, parallel-processing

I have a program that is supposed to run a set of other programs and collect their output for logging purposes. Everything is working fine as long as there is output to standard out.

That leads me to my two problems:

1. How can I capture both `STDIN` and `STDERR` of another program in one file?
2. If there is no output at all (or output to `STDERR` only) the program will get stuck on the line:

   ```
   while (<$input>)
   ```

How can I make the program wait for possible output from another program of indeterminate run time, and still continue if there is no output by the time the program finishes execution.

Here is that section of the code

```
my $pid = open (my $input, '-|', "$prog $args")
        or push @errors, "A failute has occurred in $prog $args";
if(not @errors){
    while (<$input>){ #POSSIBLE LOCATION FOR HANG UP IF NO PRINTING IS DONE
        if($input =~ /^END\n$/){
            last;
        }
        print $fh $_;
    }
}
else{
    print $fh "An error has occurred with executing \"$prog $args\"";
}
```

note: `$fh` is my file handler used to write to my log file, and `@errors` is used for internally reporting errors in my program.

EDIT:
One problem I experienced with trying the [Proc::Reliable](http://p3rl.org/Proc%3a%3aReliable) route is that it seems to have after effects on `STDOUT` and `STDERR`, and I would need to fix those after each call to run. This leads to another problem in my code. I am running in parallel and any change to `STDOUT` and `STDERR` effect all of the threads *(using Windows at least)*.

[IO::CaptureOutput](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aCaptureOutput) has the same issue for me, but it tries to correct the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` jumbling internally and causes the following error to occur:

```
Couldn't remove temp file 'C:\Users\SBLAKE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\m8E3pUGfOS' - Permission denied at C:/Perl/site/lib/IO/CaptureOutput.pm line 82
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you capture stderr, stdout, and the exit code all at once, in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109124/how-do-you-capture-stderr-stdout-and-the-exit-code-all-at-once-in-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you launch from a POSIX-like shell, then the `2>&1` notation sends standard error to the same place as the standard output:

```
some-program-to-be-logged 2>&1 | perl logger.pl -o /chosen/log.file
```

Both standard output and standard error are sent to the standard input of the Perl logging script.

The input loop in the logger script will hang waiting until there is input to read, or until all the processes with the pipe open for writing close the pipe (typically because they exit).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Proc::Reliable](http://p3rl.org/Proc::Reliable), it seems to be what you want.

See also:

- [How do you capture stderr, stdout, and the exit code all at once, in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109124/how-do-you-capture-stderr-stdout-and-the-exit-code-all-at-once-in-perl)
- [Capture::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Capture::Tiny)
- [IO::CaptureOutput](http://p3rl.org/IO::CaptureOutput)