# how to capture gzip error message in perl script

Tags: perl, stderr

I am getting zipping error when I try to open the zip file. I want to capture that error msg. Plz help me in doing that. I need the solution in perl.

eg::

gzcat zipfile.gz

gzip: zipfile.gz: unexpected end of file

I want to capture "unexpected end of file" into a variable.

How can I do that in **PERL**??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this module can help:

http://metacpan.org/pod/IO::CaptureOutput

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect your stderr output . One way to do this (might depend on your shell though), is -

```
my $res = `mycommand 2>&1`;
print "output + errors: $res\n"
```

There are also other suggestions here -
[How do you capture stderr, stdout, and the exit code all at once, in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109124/how-do-you-capture-stderr-stdout-and-the-exit-code-all-at-once-in-perl)