# Validating the xml against XSD In xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, perl, xslt, xsd, xmlstarlet

I am Validating many XML files against the given XSD. It is printing some errors in Command line. I need that errors into one variable.

I am using Perl. I tried below things, but couldn't able to get the my requirement.

```
$values = system("xmlstarlet val --err --xsd Test.xsd Test1.xml");
```

return as 0 or 1

```
$values = `xmlstarlet val --err --xsd Test.xsd Test1.xml`
```

Errors looks like this

> **test.xml:5340.23: Element 'SP': This element is not expected.**

It is printing only valid or invalid, I need above mentioned error also.

I used the following command

```
**xmlstarlet val --err --xsd Test.xsd Test1.xml**
```

Let me know some ideas to get the errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109124/how-do-you-capture-stderr-stdout-and-the-exit-code-all-at-once-in-perl

Comment: @UmeshPerl... But I haven't suggested anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code;

```
my $error; 
my $values = `xmlstarlet val --err --xsd Test.xsd Test1.xml 2>&1`;

if ($?) {
    $error = $values;
}
```