# Executing command and storing output in array variable

Tags: python, perl, popen

```
p = Popen(our_cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0]
split = output.strip('\n\t\r').split("\n")
```

I want to execute this command which is in string `our_cmd`

what I have tried is this

```
my @output = `$our_cmd`; ## here command is executing
my @split = grep(s/\s*$//g, @output); ## the format and putting in new array
@split = split("\n", @split);
```

My command is executing but not taking input properly. I need output in array in format as in Python code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you capture stderr, stdout, and the exit code all at once, in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109124/how-do-you-capture-stderr-stdout-and-the-exit-code-all-at-once-in-perl)

Comment: Can you give some example of the output you're parsing?

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna: The return code and the contents of `stderr` are being ignored in that Python code

Comment: your Python code accumulates `stderr` in memory and then just discards it at the end. To get stdout lines from a shell command as a list and to discard its stderr: `lines = check_output(out_cmd, shell=True, stderr=DEVNULL).splitlines()`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from your question, all you need is

```
my @split = `$our_cmd`;
chomp @split;
```

Comment: I wasn't sure about the `strip` - that looks like it's deleting some characters I think?

Comment: @Sobrique: It's removing all tabs, newlines, and carriage returns from the beginning and end of the string. Otherwise `split` will return an empty string at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding a couple of perl concepts here. For example - you're `split`ing an array - which doesn't make a lot of sense, because `split` turns a *string* into an array, based on a delimiter.

Likewise `grep` - that's quite an unusual use of `grep` because you've got a search and replace pattern embedded - usually `grep` is for filtering based on some boolean expression. (I suspect it works like that, but I'm not entirely sure if your replacement pattern returns true/false, which'll do odd things in a `grep` context).

So how about instead:

```
my @output = `$our_command`;

chomp @output; #removes linefeeds from each element. 

for ( @output ) { s/[\t\r]//g; }; #removes linefeeds and carriage returns
```

This will put into `@output` one element per line (including linefeed) and then remove any `\t` or `\r` in there. If you don't want the linefeed, as Borodin says - `chomp @output;` will deal with that.

As mentioned in comments - this may not exactly reproduce what `strip` is doing, and the `strip` operation may be irrelevant in perl.

Testing your grep:

```
my @test =  ( "test aaa bbb", "mooo", " aaa Moo MMOoo", "no thing in it" );
print join ("\n", grep { s/aaa//g } @test );
```

This *does* do the search and replace on `$_` (each line of the `grep`), but the replace expression does return a 'true/false' - meaning you effectively discard elements that don't contain the pattern at all.

Comment: The Python code only removes those characters from the beginning of the first line and the end of the last line of the output. There should never be any CR characters anyway.